# why object is looking gray instead being transparent when alpha parameter of gl_FragColor is lower than 1 in fragment shader

Tags: opengl-es, shader, glsles

When I set the alpha value of gl_FragColor to 1 here is the result.
[image: Render with alpha value of gl_FragColor set to 1]

However if I set it to 0.5 thats what I see, but not anything transperent is this normal?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you enabled alpha blending in your renderer?

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

More meaty stuff:
[Tutorial 10 : Transparency](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-10-transparency/)